# response redirect to a different page when 405 raise

Tags: python, django

I have a view function which I want to use only request method is POST. I got to know about [require_POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST) decorator here, but what I want is that if method is not POST then redirect user to different view using `HttpResponseRedirect`. How can I do this ?

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def my_view(request):
    # I can assume now that only POST requests make it this far
    # ...
```

I know I can do it by adding two lines of code, without using require_POST redirect in my method itself like

```
if request.method != 'POST':
    return HttpResponseRedirect(view_url)
```

but I am more interested in using decorator itself and when this decorator raises 405, then redirect to another view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom decorator is the way to go.

I myself use one similar to the one you need and I'll post the code.

Do upvote @aychedee s answer since he was first. :)

```
def require_post_decorator(function=None, redirect_url='/'):
    def _decorator(view_function):
        def _view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                #do some before the view is reached stuffs here.
                return view_function(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

        _view.__name__ = view_function.__name__
        _view.__dict__ = view_function.__dict__
        _view.__doc__ = view_function.__doc__

        return _view

    if function:
        return _decorator(function)
    return _decorator
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a custom decorator. You can see the code for the [Django decorator here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/decorators/http.py). It's already returned a response before your code is reached at all, so absolutely nothing you do in your view function would be run anyway.

There is nothing wrong with manually returning a redirect if the request is not a POST. If you use this pattern in a few different places in your code I would then refactor it into a decorator later. But if this is the first place you are using it then it's overkill.